# How do I send Chars to a text Input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard

In my project: [CSSHTML Keyboard](https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/VNLMVZ) I have setup a keyboard based off my old laptop keyboard, it was a small project I made as a homework piece for school. The issue is, Im not sure how to add the Specific Chars to the keyboard, like, for example: Say I click **Shift** and then **A/a**, I want it to place "A" in the input. If someone could bring me a little information for this, I would appreciate it. Also for the later notice, Im not trying to make *Every* key work like it should, only base keys (Letters, Numbers, Capitalization, Set Symbols, Caps Lock, Shift, Space, and Backspace)

I made a Calculator: [Simple Calculator](https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/ZPRjQy)
and I tried using a similar method of sending a symbol/character to the Input, but it didn't seem to work well.

the method I tried was by using an input:

```
<input id="butn" class="output" type="textfield" name="ans" value="!The 
Text input is Currently Not Available!"></input>
```

and then using a small bit of Javascript to send math equations from buttons to the form and then to the input, then solving them with an evaluation Javascript snippet

Here is the link to the current code: [CSSHTML Keyboard Finished](https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/VNLMVZ)

By the way, apologies if the keyboard is put together "duck tape and glue" style, I'm still decently new to perfecting CSS Sizing and aligning, so for now I write everything manually with margins and sizing.

After a while of testing the calculator method above that I used, I had managed to sorta get it to work at one point, but it placed undefined, so in a way I kind of gave up on the project temporarily, Either way, I'm happy with my finished Product, even if I cant use it to type out the characters.

Comment: Is the code between the two projects so different that you can't compare them to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: By the way, I once made a calculator that doesn't use JavaScript at all. Pure CSS. But I'm not sure that's on topic here.

Comment: @MrLister interesting, Im guessing it has to do with exchanging the numbers via Visibiity or Dispay Hidden or Shown? Or does it actually use some kind of counter/math evaluator..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this simple JS to get the keydown event, get the value of the pressed key and print it in the input.

Then you should configure keys that you don't want to be written when you type them ( especial actions for example)

I've put the backspace and some example keys for you.

```
var output = document.querySelector('.output');

addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     

    // Backspace 
    if ( e.key === 'Backspace' ){
        output.value = output.value.substr( 0, ( output.value.length -1 ) );    

    // The values you dont want to write literally
    } else if( e.key === 'Shift'     || 
               e.key === 'Control'   ||
               e.key === 'Alt'       ||
               e.key === 'AltGraph'   ) {

        output.value += '';

    }   else {
        // The keydown values
        output.value += e.key;
    }   
});
```

### additions

For the question about how to send value with a button:

First you must set "something" for select them with js (for example a class),
and you should set a value attribute tu get it later.

```
<button type="button" class="letter keys" value="1" >!<br>1</button>
```

Then select all buttons with a loop and add an event when click them.

At last just take the attributes.value of the element and do what you want with it.

here is an example:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');

for( let button of buttons ){
    button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        console.log(button.attributes.value);       
    })
}
```

That will work for you but i recomend you to read something more about basics of JS to manage all you want to do before this, because this is only the beginning.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Im still relatively new to Javascript, How do I reference all the keys EXCEPT specific ones, like All the Letters, but ignoring Alt, Ctrl, the F#s, the Esc, prntscr, Shift, enter, page controls, and win key

Comment: I believe I actually managed to connect the backspace key to the example you included, but I cant connect the letters for some reason,

Comment: Wow annnd Now I believe I actually broke it, Im tapping the backspace key on the keyboard and it does nothing, but when I hit my backspace in the real life keyboard, it places "Backspace" in the input over and over, Details are in the project.

Comment: @TaylorSpark  your mistake is because JS is case sensitive and your 'backspace' needs to be 'Backspace' like this:
    if ( e.key === 'Backspace' ){                                                                                    Here yo are telling js that the output when you press 'Backspace' is the previous outpus less the last character:
        output.value = output.value.substr( 0, ( output.value.length -1 ) )

Comment: @TaylorSpark to know the key just type and the keyboard retuns you the literally name, then you can work with it.                                                                                              I let you some more info of the event you canread: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown , if you have more doubts here we are.

Comment: @TaylorSpark the example es configured to listen the keydown events only, you can use another equal function changing the event 'keydown' to the event 'click' and then configure key with mouse too.

Comment: Still a bit confused, I just took a basics introduction course to javascript, I still dont legitimately know some of these terms, sorry I've been going off basic tutorials and some f my own knowledge for the past couple months. Yet with all the tutorials, Im still not able to find a simple way to make a button send text to an input

Comment: @TaylorSpark i eddited the main response with a bit additions for you because easier to explain there.

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense now :)

Comment: Okay... Sorry to bug you again, it seems this still did not solve the issue.. Im kinda tiring myself out over this now hah!